# How do I configure Geany to do code completion for Rust?

Tags: rust, geany

I am trying to learn Rust, and I like Geany. I don't know how to do code completion with Geany.  I have all of the settings turned on for it, but it only recognises C++ syntax for code completion/assist, not Rust. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible for Geany now, at least according to https://areweideyet.com/

For now, the most stable tool in rust for completion is [rust-analyzer](https://github.com/rust-analyzer/rust-analyzer). It works over Language-Server Protocol, but it seems to be [missing](https://github.com/geany/geany/issues/2184) in Geany.